# Forcing Beyond Compare to use tabs when used as an external diff tool in Bazaar Explorer

Tags: bazaar, beyondcompare, tortoisebzr

I'm trying to use Beyond Compare as my diff tool in Bazaar Explorer.

`In Settings` > `Configuration` > `User Configuration` > `Diff`

I added

Name: `Beyond Compare`

Command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe`

Note: No quotes.

This works fine, as in if i right click a folder, `Tortoise Bazaar` > `Diff` > `External Diff` > `Beyond Compare`

Then Beyond Compare opens and shows me the diff on the first file. However, if there are many files with changes in a folder. I have to close Beyond Compare only for it to reopen with the next changed file. How to i get all the changed files to open as separate tabs in the same Beyond Compare window?

I have tried `BComp.com`, `BComp.exe` and `BCompare.exe` and none seem to work as i want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may have been [improved](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~qbzr-dev/qbzr/trunk2a/revision/1467) in qbzr 0.23, which is compatible with bzr 2.6, of which the [second beta](https://launchpad.net/bzr/2.6/2.6b2) is currently available.